# Debugging LDAP with shiro in Tomcat

Tags: debugging, tomcat, authentication, shiro

I have a web service, and for that I want to authenticate users.

I'm trying to have a form based authentication with org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm as my realm.

But when I enter the credentials nothing happens but redirecting to login page again. And there's nothing get printed on the log.

My Question is how can I debug the shiro to figure out what is happening?

Edit: 
Here is my shiro ini file

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.successUrl = /index.jsp

ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = sAMAccountName={0},DC=aaa,DC=bbb
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://aaa.bbb.ccc:3268
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername = admin
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword= password 
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm


[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

Edit 2: my login jsp

```
<form name="loginform" method="post">
    plain
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <br/>
        <label for="rememberMe">Remember me:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" value="true" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

my web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Care to share the shiro's ini file ? some code perhaps ?

Comment: Thanks @FerdinandNeman . I've edited my post. please look.

Comment: are you sure that you created your filters and JSP according to the [manual](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html) ? such as, default user and password request parameters, etc.

Comment: Hi @FerdinandNeman, yes my filters and jsp's work fine if I use an ini file as folllows.

Comment: [main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
user.loginUrl = /login.jsp

[users]
admin = password

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/** = user

Comment: That's why I guessed that there is something wrong with my LDAP realm

Comment: Could you add your login.jsp into your question, only the login form part. Or better, together with the web.xml

Comment: how can I check whether tomcat is even trying to connect to the ldap server or not.

Comment: The best clue to look at, is to set the log level to DEBUG for package "org.apache.shiro" ... do some login, and observe the produce log file. Log file like in this [link](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/LDAP-help-not-authenticating-but-no-error-message-either-td7580267.html) may prove very useful.

Comment: Many Thanks @FerdinandNeman.. looks like that thread will lead me to somewhere near. Thanks again